# Perl + Error in video tag - <video> tag is not working

Tags: html, perl

I am writing the simple script to play the video file but it is not able to play that.

here is my code but it is not working code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Content-type: text/html \n\n";
print <<EOF;
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="/home/abhishek/Videos/lua.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
EOF
```

My error log file is writing that file does not exist

```
[Tue Dec 29 13:08:07 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/home, referer: http://localhost/cgi-bin/download.cgi
```

Even though i kept the file in that path but it is unable to play it.

I don't know where it is going wrong.
Any help will be grateful.Thanks in advice.

Comment: It must be a path issues

Comment: Is `perl` indeed located in `/usr/bin`? On some systems it is in `/usr/local/bin`, `/opt/local/bin` or other locations. Or it may not be installed at all. What happens when you run the script directly from the command line (shell)?  Note that the error most certainly has nothing to do with the `<video>` tag at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<source src="/home/abhishek/Videos/lua.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

The `src` attribute needs to be a URL, not a file path. You need to a) move your video to somewhere where your web server can access it (so, probably, somewhere under /var/www) and b) change the `src` attribute to point to the correct URL.

N.B. This has nothing at all to do with Perl. You could have tested that by creating an HTML page with the same tags in it. That would have failed in exactly the same way.

Comment: how can i give url path??

Comment: Well it varies depending on how your web server is configured. But one standard approach is for your document root to be /var/www. If that's the case and you put your video in that directory, the URL would be "/lua.mp4". If you put it in /var/www/videos then the URL would be "/videos/lua.mp4". And so on.

Comment: i was missing the '/' from the file name..now it works thanku